# Processing only visible form fields for validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to validate a bunch of form fields within one  element. I just need them all to be 'required', not necessarily input checked (email, phone number, etc). The problem is, I have the form dynamically showing and hiding inputs and select elements, and I need the validator to ignore hidden ones.

I have looked into this a fair amount - this, in theory, should work:

```
$('#theform').validate( {required: "input:visible,select:visible"}
```

It doesn't, the page just submits. There are several examples on [this](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) page, but I can't get any of them working. It's possible I'm implementing them wrongly.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use the [`ignore` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) here, like this:

```
$('#theform').validate({ ignore: ':hidden' });
```

I use this option to skip validation of dialogs that aren't presented for example, short and simple solution to the problem :)

Comment: @Gavin - Do you have a link to an example page?  It sounds like you have a JavaScript error where it's not hooking up validation at all...if my code above didn't work the symptoms would be the hidden fields *still* validating, not the form skipping validation altogether, so something else must be happening here.

Comment: Of course it was something simple.. I *completely* forgot to add parameters within the form, i.e. class names to reflect the requirements. Done and it works beautifully. ignore: ':hidden' was a much better way to go about it. Thanks!